# Unable to Schedule local notification in Qt android

Tags: android, c++, qt, notifications, qt5

I am trying to create local scheduled notifications with Qt for android app. I was following this answer : [Unable to schedule notification with AlarmManager on Android (using Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901869/unable-to-schedule-notification-with-alarmmanager-on-android-using-qt#) but i am not able to get it working .

Below is the code
notificationclient.h :

```
#ifndef NOTIFICATIONCLIENT_H
#define NOTIFICATIONCLIENT_H

#include <QObject>

class NotificationClient : public QObject
{

    explicit NotificationClient(QObject *parent = 0);

    int createNotification(Qstring title, Qstring content);



};

#endif // NOTIFICATIONCLIENT_H
```

notificationclient.cpp

```
#include "notificationclient.h"

#include <QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidJniObject>

NotificationClient::NotificationClient(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{

}



int NotificationClient::createNotification(Qstring title, Qstring content);
{
    QAndroidJniObject javaNotification = QAndroidJniObject;
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("ScheduledNotifications",
                                       "createNotification",
                                       "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                       javaNotification.object<jstring>());
}
```

ScheduleNotification.java

```
class ScheduledNotifications {
    static public int notification_id = 0;
    static int scheduleNotification(String title, String content, int futureInMilliseconds) {
        ++notification_id;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(QtNative.activity(),  NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification_id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, createNotification(title,content));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(QtNative.activity(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)QtNative.activity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, /*futureInMilliseconds*/0, pendingIntent);

        Log.d("!" ,"Scheduled");
        return notification_id;
    }

    static public Notification createNotification(String title, String content) {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(QtNative.activity());


            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(content);
            return builder.build();
    }
}
```

NotificationPublisher.java

```
class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {//Called when its time to show the notification ...

        Log.d("!", "Notified");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

I am not really sure how to do it . If someone can provide a proper example with local notification in Qt that would be really helpful

thanks!!

Comment: what is the meaning of *but i am not able to get it working*?

Comment: what i meant was that like in my mind i have general idea what has to be done , a java class , a java reciver class and c++ class to call them using JNI but i am not able to fomulate it in code .

This is the problem ( lack of knowledge) . that's why i am asking if someone can create a simple example for it .

Comment: Have you tried something ?, without any idea of criticizing your question, I recommend trying something, showing where you got stuck and maybe we could give you advice, asking for code many times without showing an attempt does not attract people. That's why it was my question because I thought you had tried something and something did not work, and I was asking about that something.

Comment: Hey i have definitely tried something . here is the repo for that : https://github.com/hackertron/jni.git ( it's same code as i provided above). When i run the project ( deploy on my android ) i get no notification nothing. Just plain qt quick application.